# how to load my file system and vmlinux on Zedboard

Tags: linux, riscv, zynq

I had followed the steps in https://github.com/ucb-bar/fpga-zynq and boot riscv-linux successfully on Zedboard via command `./fesvr-zynq +disk=/sdcard/riscv/root.bin bbl /sdcard/riscv/vmlinux`.

But I found a problem that when I use myself vmlinux and root.bin via command `./fesvr-zynq +disk=/sdcard/my/fs.img bbl /sdcard/my/vmlinux-riscv64`,it seems that the file system is not myself `fs.img` because it has different files from my `fs.img` in path `/bin`.

AND  I found that when I delete the all files in directory /sdcard/riscv and use a command `./fesvr-zynq bbl`, the riscv-linux runs! Is the `bbl` file contains `boot-loader` and `vmlinux`?

Comment: What is your Zedboard? And what version of fpga-zynq was used?

Comment: I have solved the problem. Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: Can you post the solution as answer (& provide little more details about board)?